# How to work with the WHILE loop constructor while constructing proofs in the simple imperative language of SF

Tags: while-loop, coq, language-design

In the IMP chapter of SF, I don't know how to work with the while statements (particularly, the E_WhileTrue constructor).  In the below code I'm getting a unification error.

This is not a problem in the book, but an example I made up.

Can you please explain how I can work through multiple loops in a while loop so that I can understand how to complete this example

```
Example ceval_example1234:
  empty_st =[
     X ::= 2;;
     WHILE X <= 2
       DO Y ::= 3 ;; X ::= X + 1
     END
  ]=> (X !-> 3; Y !-> 3 ; X !-> 2).
Proof.
  (* We must supply the intermediate state *)
  apply E_Seq with (X !-> 2).
  - (* assignment command *)
    apply E_Ass. reflexivity.
  - apply E_WhileTrue with (Y !-> 3; X !-> 2). simpl.  reflexivity.
    apply E_Seq with ( Y !-> 3; X !-> 2).
    apply E_Ass. reflexivity.
```

Everything below here is more or less what I want to do to finish the proof.

```
    apply E_Ass. reflexivity.
    apply E_WhileFalse.
    reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
Example ceval_example1234:
  empty_st =[
     X ::= 2;;
     WHILE X <= 2
       DO Y ::= 3 ;; X ::= X + 1
     END
  ]=> (X !-> 3; Y !-> 3 ; X !-> 2).
Proof.
  (* We must supply the intermediate state *)
  apply E_Seq with (X !-> 2).
  - (* assignment command *)
    apply E_Ass. reflexivity.
  - apply E_WhileTrue with (X !-> 3; Y !-> 3; X !-> 2). simpl.  reflexivity.
    apply E_Seq with ( Y !-> 3; X !-> 2).
    apply E_Ass. reflexivity.
    apply E_Ass. simpl. reflexivity.
    apply E_WhileFalse.
    simpl. reflexivity.
Qed.
```